# Hadoop hangs because it cannot reach other instances by hostname

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, host, resourcemanager

Hadoop job hangs, after being accepted at this step.

```
INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1412689235580_0001
```

After checking log files I am getting this error in resource manager log file.
the host which is mentioned in below error is not defined by me.It is not the name of any of VM I am using or accessing.I am not able to figure out from where it is taking this host name.

[image: log error page]

My core-site.xml is :-

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://hadoopmaster:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

My yarn-site.xml is :-

```
<configuration>
<property>

<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>

</property>  
<property>

    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>

</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
    <value>HadoopMaster:8025</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
    <value>HadoopMaster:8035</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
    <value>HadoopMaster:8050</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

/etc/hosts file contents:-

```
127.0.0.1       localhost 
127.0.1.1       servervm.cse.abc.ernet.in cse.abc.ac.in abc.ernet.in i$ 

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts 
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback 
fe00::0 ip6-localnet 
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix 
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes 
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters 

179.16.114.11 HadoopMaster 
179.16.114.12 hadoopslave1 
179.16.114.13 hadoopslave2 
179.16.114.14 hadoopslave3
```

I uninstalled whole cluster and did fresh installation,still facing same issue.
I am using Ubuntu 12.04 on my vms and Hadoop 2.6.0